# Bluetooth mouse disconnects every ~30 seconds

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, bluetooth

I am running Linux Mint 16 Petra, and I have a Bluetooth mouse that I would like to use with it. Unfortunately, the mouse disconnects around every 30 seconds and has to be rebooted by physically turning the power button on the mouse off and on again to reconnect. The Bluetooth adapter is identified as a `ASUSTek Computer, Inc. BT-253 Bluetooth Adapter`.

How can I make the mouse stay connected?

Comment: This sounds like a faulty hardware device or perhaps the batteries are dying?

Comment: @slm The batteries should be fine and the mouse works good under Windows 7. However, it does sometimes say that the mouse is low on power when it disconnects. But the mouse blinks when it actually is low on power, and I suspect that the power readings might be inverted because the batteries are fully charged and are reported as 0% power left. Some less charged ones reported low power as 17% left.

Comment: Yes I suspect that the power reading coming from the mouse to the system is getting confused by the system and so it's thinking the mouse has lost power and is disconnecting it.

Comment: @slm But is there any way I can try to invert the power readings?

Answer (score 3):

Given your description of the issue it sounds like some sort of problem where the mouse is being perceived by the receiver/driver stack on the system as though it has lost (or is losing) power and so it is being disconnected.

Searching for this issue I did come across this Ubuntu issue which I think might be at play here as well. There were several suggestions within this thread, which I suspect might be several problems being rolled into it, but regardless there are several good looking leads which might help with your issue as well.

- [050d:0017 Bluetooth mouse randomly disconnects](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1072234)

I would start with the version of BlueZ, and see if you can't get a newer version upstream from the developers since you're using Linux Mint (which derives from Ubuntu). I might also try getting an updated Linux kernel (another suggestion in the thread).

Also to debug the issue further I'd look for any relevant output in your `dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog`'s for messages that might help narrow the focus a bit.

Answer (score 0):

An old thread. Have a similar issue on Mint Cinnamon 21. But it disconnects only once after around 30s. If I touch Mouse button than it keeps connection.
I don't have this behavior under Windows (same laptop, same mouse).
I would suspect some energy saving issue - just to make sure the mouse is not activated accidentally. Can I get rid of this?